# Why Teichmüller map is multiplicative

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In Serre's *Local Fields*, it says that the Teichmüller map $r : A → W(A), x → [x] = (x, 0, ... , 0, ...)$ is multiplicative. But I don't understand. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, does it mean that the Teichmüller map is $r : \mathbb{F}_p → W(\mathbb{F}_p)=\mathbb{Z}_p$,  $ r([x])=x$, where $0 \leq x\leq p$? But I don't think it's correct since it's not multiplicative, and it's not the same with the definition in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_character).

Comment: The Witt vector $(a,0,0,\ldots)$ is NOT (mapped to) the integer $a$ when $1<a<p$. Rather, it is the root of unity of order $d$,  $d\mid p-1$, congruent to $a$ modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in suspecting that the natural assignment you suggest is not the definition of the Teichmuller map. See [2.1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt_vector) here.